# powershell any search a large text file faster

Tags: powershell

```
$File="C:\temp\test\ID.txt"
$line="ART.023.AGA_203.PL"

Measure-Command {$Sel = Select-String  -pattern $line -path $File } 

Measure-Command {
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($File)
    $content = $reader.ReadToEnd().Split('`n')
    $results = $content | select-string -Pattern $line
    }

Measure-Command {
        $content= get-content $File
        $results = $content | select-string -Pattern $line
        $results
        }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 197
Ticks             : 1970580
TotalDays         : 2.28076388888889E-06
TotalHours        : 5.47383333333333E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.0032843
TotalSeconds      : 0.197058

TotalMilliseconds : 197.058

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4
Milliseconds      : 135
Ticks             : 41350664
TotalDays         : 4.78595648148148E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00114862955555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.0689177733333333
TotalSeconds      : 4.1350664

TotalMilliseconds : 4135.0664

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4
Milliseconds      : 926
Ticks             : 49265692
TotalDays         : 5.70204768518518E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00136849144444444
TotalMinutes      : 0.0821094866666667
TotalSeconds      : 4.9265692
TotalMilliseconds : 4926.5692
```

i want to search about 10000 $line in $File

search time very slower,any faster?

example :

search Keyword:$line ,then $File will show line

Keyword:ART.023.AGA_203.PL

file:2,45433;ART.023.AGA_203.PL;dddd;wwww;tt;

Comment: How exactly are 197 milliseconds "very slow"? The time-consuming step in the 2nd and 3rd example is obviously reading the file from disk into memory, so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

How does this compare to your other methods?

```
Measure-Command {
 Get-Content $file -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {$_ -match $line}
}
```

Note: when comparison testing operations that do disk reads like this, always run multiple tests and discard the first one. If the disk has any on-board read cache, the first test can pre-load the cache for subsequent tests and skew the results.